# Why is the front fans of my PC stay powered with my HDMI switch

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi, gpu

Here's an odd one for you...

I have two monitors. The second monitor I have a HDMI switch to switch between my PC and a USB-C hub that goes into my MacBook Pro. On the USB-C hub I have a HDMI output (the one that goes to the HDMI switch) and a USB-C port for charging my laptop while I use it so I can just use it as if it was just a standard computer plugged into a monitor.

At first I could hear a sound and I thought it was my GPU - which got me worried - but as soon as I unplugged my USB-C charging cable from my USB-C hub the noise stopped? Then I realized it was the front fans of my PC still spinning, even though the computer is still off. If I change the input on the HDMI switch then the fans stop spinning and the noise from them goes away - as if power is going from my Macbook's USB-C charging cable through the USB-C hub, through the HDMI lead, through the HDMI switch and into my PC. What is going on?!

Is this dangerous for my PC, I think from what I can tell it's only the fans getting affected but still, I'm worried for my GPU, how is this happening?

My PC motherboard is an ASUS ROG x299-e

and here's a link to the switch: [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HDMI-Switch-Bidirectional-Splitter-Supports/dp/B076VJ7XZV/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8)

funnily enough a same guy had the same issue in the products reviews: [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-reviews/R3J5E1WC270R18/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B076VJ7XZV)

Comment: I have this exact same issue, USB C to HDMI cable from MacBook Pro 2018 to HDMI Switch, to the PC, and when I shut off the PC, the CPU and back fans continue spinning until I unplug the USB C to HDMI cable from the MacBook. I doubt it's dangerous, but it sure is weird. My motherboard is ASRock though. The fans spin even if I unpower EVERYTHING, so it's clearly coming only from the MBP.

Comment: Similar issue, although it's a Dell laptop not a Macbook, HDMI switch connects my PC and Laptop to the monitor. I have another finding, my PC has an APU as well as GPU, when I connect the HDMI cable to the APU the fan doesn't spin, but if connected to GPU it spins.

Answer (score 1):

USB-C works at higher data rates and supports higher power amperages than previous USB standards.  This means USB-C hardware generates more heat.  The hardware is likely generating heat that your system needs to dissipate.

Comment: I don't think you've understood my question... The USB-C hub is an external thing to my PC, the only thing that's related between the two is the HDMI port that goes out of the HDMI switch and into my PC. It happens when my PC is off too, which is what I explained in my question.